# Allocating a private buffer and using a pointer to modify the contents

Tags: c++, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

I want to allocate memory for a private uint32_t array in the class `A` with the `allocate_buffer(...)` function, which takes the size of the array and an uninitialized pointer (`void *data`) pointer.

The pointer should be used to access the memory of `A::buffer`, such that it is possible to use `memcpy(...)` to copy data to the array with

```cpp
memcpy(pointer_to_buffer, some_src_data, sizeof(some_src_data));
```

#### prg.hpp

the class with a private buffer and to functions for allocating and printing

```cpp
#ifndef PRG_HPP
#define PRG_HPP

#include <cstdint>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    private:
        void *buffer;
        size_t count;

    public:
        void allocate_buffer(size_t size, void **data) {
            buffer = malloc(size);
            count = size;
            data = &buffer;
        }
        void print_buffer() {
            auto data = (uint32_t*)buffer;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

#### main.cpp

a simple program, which uses prg.hpp

```cpp
#include "prg.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main(void) {
    // An objected of class A gets created
    A a = {};

    // A simple vector with ints up to 100, which acts as the src for malloc
    std::vector<uint32_t> ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ints.push_back(i);
    }

    // buffer of object a is allocated and data should now be a pointer to the buffer
    void *data;
    size_t size = sizeof(uint32_t) * ints.size();
    a.allocate_buffer(size, &data);

    // Using the pointer to copy the contents of the vector ints to the buffer of object a
    memcpy(data, ints.data(), size);

    // Presentation
    a.print_buffer();
    return 0;
}
```

#### PS: Execution gives a segfault

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing such a thing?  `A` should have a `std::vector<uint32_t>` if that is what you want it to store.

Comment: Did you mean `*data = buffer;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, the type of the buffer will be unknown/dynamic, so i have to use void*

Comment: @SHGuy_ If that is the case, then your print buffer function can't work because you don't know what to cast it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
    void allocate_buffer(size_t size, void **data) {
        buffer = malloc(size);
        count = size;
        data = &buffer;  // damned!
    }
```

In a function or method, the parameters are local variables and if you change them you only change a local variable which vanishes at the end of the function (its lifetime is ended in C++ wordings).

You correctly passed the address of a pointer: just use it:

```
        *data = buffer;  // good...
```

That way you change the value of the caller's pointer.

---

But as you have been told in comment, such low level memory operation is not the C++ idiomatic way. There is nothing bad in testing and learning, but do not do that in real world programs without a strong reason.

Comment: Thx, solved it. Noticed a second error, where the size in bytes is used in the print function